# WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection and ServiceConfiguration, Azure

Tags: c#, azure, web-config, connection-string

I have problems making

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(string connectionStringName, string userTableName, string userIdColumn, string userNameColumn, bool autoCreateTables)
```

to be configured with ServiceConfiguration.[env] in windows azure.

The problem is that **WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection** takes **string connectionStringName** and when im passing in my **connectionStringName** for the **InitializeDatabaseConnection** method it only looks in web.config for the corresponding value.

I know how to get the connectionstring from connectionStringName, I can use

```
  var connectionString =  CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("connectionStringName");
```

But still, **InitializeDatabaseConnection** need argument **connectionStringName** and not **connectionString** and therefore i need it to look in ServiceConfiguration to lookup the corresponding value for the given argument(connectionStringName).

So my question is: 
**Is it possible to use ServiceConfiguration.[env].cscfg for WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection and let it lookup value in ServiceConfiguration from a given name**?
And if so , **how to make it work?**

Comment: CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting will default to we.config if the value isn't in ServiceConfiguration.[env].cscfg - try just using the connectionStringName from the web.config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the other overload of `InitializeDatabaseConnection` and pass it a provider name:

```
public static void InitializeDatabaseConnection(
            string connectionString, 
            string providerName, 
            string userTableName, 
            string userIdColumn, 
            string userNameColumn, 
            bool autoCreateTables)
```

For example:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("connectionStringName"), "System.Data.SqlClient", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", true);
```